# How can I navigate to Storyboard VC from SwiftUI View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I created this SwiftUI View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            MasterView()
        }.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct MasterView: View {
     var body: some View {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Geplant")) {
                    Section {
                        NavigationLink(destination: /* How can I navigate to a Storyboard ViewController?*/) { Text("Berlin") }

                    }
                
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Wähle Reise")
    }
}
```

As you can read, I want to navigate at line "NavigationLink(destination: .....) to a Storyboard VC.

Before, I navigated to the SwiftUI ContentView using a UIHostingController from a UIKit VC.

Does anyone can help me?

Feel free to ask me for other Code/ Screenshots :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

```
struct UIKitView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIKitViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIKitViewController {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "UIKitViewController") as! UIKitViewController
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIKitViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

And then now use

```
NavigationLink(destination: UIKitView()) { Text("Berlin") }
```

Comment: Awesome! I just copied it below my code, but it says "Type 'UIKitView' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerRepresentable'" , "Cannot find type 'UIKitViewController' in scope", what do I have to import?

Comment: Or do I have to replace UIKitViewController with something?

Comment: UIKitViewController this one is for my demo version. you need to replace with your controller name.

Comment: This worked well for me when interfacing between SwiftUI and Nib based ViewController written in Objective-C.